# Displace modifier does not work in 2.81

Tags: displacement

if i want to add a procedural texture to displace modifier which works with "Texture Node Editor" (Shift F3) it will never works am i doing something wrong ? or is this a bug ?
the texture always outputs black , the only way to use the texture is to paint it in a "Image" texture which will not be procedural anymore ,
texture Type : None
colors setting are default 
it works with texture paint but not for displace
Please respond as fast as you can .
i want a full description if its possible .
i told every thing don't ask my system specification or my birth date or other irrelevant stuff thank you .
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use a brush texture as a displacement texture. That does not work.

If you want to use a texture to displace the object, you need to create one by clicking the "New" Button in the Displace Modifier and then change the settings in the texture menu. Easy to reach with the button to the right.

[image: pic]

THERE you can change the texture. This does **NOT** work with nodes.

Keep in mind: The Texture system in Blender is End-Of-Life and will be replaced at some point with a node based approach. (afaik)

Comment: So you're  saying that blender displace modifier do not work with nodes ???

Comment: Yes. That's what it is at the moment.

Comment: I think that you're wrong about that , it should be an addon to do this ...

Comment: Well then, which one is it? Post the name/link! Vanilla Blender does not do this at the moment. It's as simple as that.

Comment: What a ridiculous thing :| how it works with image mode ? and how it works with texture painting ? this is a bug